# Solving non linear system using fsolve

Tags: matlab

Help please. I think im missing something because fsolve is too time consuming to use. I want to solve a non-linear system, and i have the system in the following form:

```
A = [x+y*3+10;
     x-z*6-15;
     x^2+y+z-16]
```

To use fsolve i need to create a function and replace every variable with v(i), something like:

```
function z=evaltub(v)
z(1) = v(1)+v(2)*3+10;
z(2) = v(1)-v(3)+6-15;
z(3) = v(1)^2+v(2)+v(3)-16;
```

and then use

```
x = fsolve(@evaltub,[1 1 1])
```

The problem is, for large systems replacing every variable with v(i) takes a lot of time.
Is there another way to use fsolve?

fsolve FINDS THE ANSWER, my problem is, i need to modify the equations to use them with fsolve, and it takes too much time when the system is big

I tried using the command solve, but when there are 10+ equations it fails to get an answer. I get the message:

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found
```

Comment: This question seems to be two separate questions. You should pick one. "I tried using the command solve, but when there are 10+ equations it fails to get an answer" – that's not helpful to us because you didn't provide the code for this case. What was returned? An error message? What was the `exitflag` output (see docs) equal to? Are you sure the system actually has roots? Did you adjust any of `fsolve`'s many options? How?

Comment: Sorry. When i use solve i get the message 'Warning: Explicit solution could not be found' I guess its because the system is too big to be solved without an initial guess? I didn't adjust any option on fsolve, it works right, but it takes too much time to modify the equations to use with fsolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see that you were talking about `solve` and not `fsolve` the first time I read your question. Yes, `solve` is generally more sensitive to the size of the system and can get very slow or just not find solutions as the number variables increases. I can't say more on that without seeing your code.

With regards to making the use of `fsolve` easier, you can do something like this:

```
function out=evaltub(in)
x = in(1);
y = in(2);
z = in(3);
A = [x+y*3+10;
     x-z*6-15;
     x^2+y+z-16];
out = A; % You could just rename A to out
```

Or, a bit more cleverly:

```
function out=evaltub(in)
inCell = num2cell(in);
[x,y,z] = inCell{:};
A = [x+y*3+10;
     x-z*6-15;
     x^2+y+z-16];
out = A; % You could just rename A to out
```